# Getting logon error in Cognos bi 10.2 while running it

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-10

Hi I am new to cognos and using the trial version of cognos(bi_dev_trial_ed_10.2.1_win_en) and getting this error while running it

Error: QE-DEF-0325 The logon failed for the following reason:RQP-DEF-0068 Unable to connect to at least one database during a multi-database attach to 1 database(s) in: 
great_outdoors_warehouse

Comment: Have you configured correctly the db in IBM Cognos Configurator?

Comment: Exactly where does this occur? You can login OK, right, it's just when you try to access reports?

Comment: yeah i can login but when i try to run the report i'm getting this error

Comment: Have you installed the sample databases? What database are they installed in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If you are working with Oracle then the problem could be that TNS_ADMIN was not setup in environment variables.*

Set the TNS_ADMIN in your windows environment variables, to the path to your tnsnames.ora file and then re-start the server.

Example: TNS_ADMIN:=oracle client/install/product/product_version/Client_1/NETWORK/ADMIN

Steps:

1. In Windows, right-click 'My Computer' icon and select 'properties'.
2. Click on the 'Advanced' tab.
3. Click on 'Environment Variables'.
4. Under the 'System Variables' pane, search for the TNS_ADMIN environment variable.
5. Click 'edit' and modify the TNS_ADMIN to include the correct path to the tnsnames.ora file and click 'OK'.

Comment: hi i'm facing the same problem but i'm using cognos express and i followed the steps whatever u've mentioned here but the error still appears. is there any alternative way for cognos express.

Comment: @coder Express is a different beast as everything is consolidated in one product..

Comment: can u tell what need to be done with respect to cognos express?

Comment: @coder i am afraid not, as i havent used express...but you could head to cognoise.com forums nad ask.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the sample databases, then set up connections to those databases.

There's a comprehensive guide here: 
http://www.cognossource.com/installing-ibm-cognos-samples/
http://www.cognossource.com/installing-ibm-cognos-samples/2/